# MySQL - Change a row value using a timer

Tags: mysql

I have been developing ban system with temporary banning system and I'm looking if there's anyway to update a row to specific value using a timer within MySQL. For instance,

I need my field `banned` to be set to 0 where the `rowid` is X.

```
UPDATE mytable SET banned=0 WHERE rowid=X
```

- But this query has to be done within X minutes or seconds specified, like if we could delay it.

- Banning a user temporarily for 60 seconds, query sent at that time:

`"UPDATE mytable SET banned=1, unbanon=NOW()+60 WHERE rowid=X"`.

Could I possibly get MySQL to automatically set `banned` variable to 0 after 60 seconds has passed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a cron job to run a query every minute that will do something like :

```
UPDATE mytable SET banned=0 WHERE unbanon <= NOW() AND banned=1
```

Comment: Could you show me an example of setting a CRON job on MySQL with this query? I'm actually a newbie on MySQL.

Comment: @Akshay http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196613/run-a-mysql-query-as-a-cron-job