# Automatic increment a field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web, backend

I' building up a browsergame. I was wondering what is the best way to build up the "money" system. i no need anything "fast". I mean, the cash cuold be updated every day \ week. Is that possible doing it automatically? Like at 00.00 of every sunday it update automatically? Of course i need to update it every time someone buy something so it shuold be auto incrementing but still modificable with php query system!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

table **wallets**: `id, user_id, amount`

```
 UPDATE wallets SET amount = amount+10
```

So you can call this query every week and it will increment all wallets by 10.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99dfe/1

Comment: I' m looking for something that automatically call that query! I mean. there is a way that the amount is added automatically?

Comment: YUP! Great Alex, thanks a lot! May i ask u if u know a good guide about it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196613/run-a-mysql-query-as-a-cron-job