# How to Detect if user is logon on other device at same time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How can I Detect, if user is logon on other device at same time.

I have tried by saving and comparing SessionID on database while login.

But in-case of abnormal logout like 'closing browser without logout' or 'session timeout', I think its nearly impossible to clear sessionid history from database.

I have googled, but didn't find any concrete answer. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe, you could use constraits in the db as UNIQUE field (for user_id in session table) for integrity. The client log in with credentials like, email, username, facebookID, you can search this in the users table and then search in session table.

Comment: Hi  @brunocascio, sorry I didn't quite understand your suggestion. 
How do you clear entry from session table on abnormal logouts?

Comment: You should use cron jobs or sql events.. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21197783/2723301 Add a timestamp field and in the sql query, check if timestamp is older.