# MySQL random auto updating field

Tags: mysql

I have a simple DB, which has a table holding a token (128 random bit integer) is there any mysql-library, option based on pure-mysql which updates that token every X time?

I could be using cron or some php scripts, but could this be achieved using only a MySQL database?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a mySQL query as a cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196613/run-a-mysql-query-as-a-cron-job)

Comment: The second Answer in the post above .. Use an `Event Scheduler`

Comment: dont use cron - cron runs also when the database is down. use the MySQL Scheduler